# Translation Gaps On Comic Conversation : 2

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters

I have translated the following:

> 那可不一定
>
> **It certainly can not be.** (*Hope this translation is correct)

Here is what I have so far..

> 三十分（？）從，大（？）會（？）吊（？） 來。

Thanks for any help to fill the gaps (?)

BTW: This is part of my series of Doraemon comic book questions

[image: Doraemon-1-2]

### UPDATE

1) Based on accepted answer this should be..

繁体: 三十分鐘後，大雄會被吊起來

2) Please check out the comments on the answer below for 大雄 (the character's name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

那可不一定

lit. That [is] probably not absolute.

means, That may be not true / the case.

三十分钟后，大雄会被吊起来

means, After 30 minutes, Nobita will be hung.

Comment: Great, Can I assume Nobita is a common name?

Comment: @TommieC. Nobita is the Japanese name of the character http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/Nobi_Nobita

Comment: @TommieC. No, Nobita is not a common Japanese name. The naive translation into Chinese should be 伸太, however, different publishers have chosen different names for this character that are completely made up. 大雄 is the most popular one. Some people believed it's liberal translation following the logic: Nobi (to extend, to stretch) => wishful name for kid to grow => prosper, vigor => 雄